# How to fix "Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn." when trying to npm init in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-init

I'm trying to run `$ npm init` in Ubuntu on my windows computer in order to create the package.json file. However, I keep getting the same error when I try to run it (node.js v8.10.0):

> Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.

I've tried searching this up elsewhere but the answers were outdated, such as re-installing nodejs with nodejs-legacy. Heres the overview of the error created:

```
root@name:~/file1# $npm init
```

> Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
>   Package 'nodejs-legacy' has no installation candidate

What should be created is a package.json file. I'm open to other forms of creating the package.json file. Or bypassing this system altogether to get the same results.